# How can I increase or decrease height between of two lines?

Tags: line, pgffor

I want to draw some lines with dots and line. This is my code.

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{Multidotfills}
\usepackage{pgffor} 
\newcommand{\foreachmultidots}[1]{\foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{\par\noindent\dotfill\par}
}
\newcommand{\foreachmultirules}[1]{
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{
        \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\newline
    }
}

\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{count}
\newcommand{\forloopmultidots}[1]{
    \forloop{count}{1}{\value{count} <#1}{
        \par\noindent\dotfill\par
    }
}
\newcommand{\forloopmultirules}[1]{
    \forloop{count}{0}{\value{count} <#1}{
        \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\newline
    }
}
\begin{document}
\textbackslash usepackage\{pgffor\}
\foreachmultidots{10}
\foreachmultirules{10}

\textbackslash usepackage\{forloop\}
\forloopmultidots{10}
\forloopmultirules{10}
\end{document}
```

How can I increase or decrease height between of two lines like the second picture?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can adjust \baselineskip.  \setlength{\baselineskip}{\dimexpr \textheight/#2}% will fill an entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a second optional parameter to your commands for the height.
(I changed the number of lines, so it fits on one page in the example.)

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{Multidotfills}
\usepackage{pgffor} 
\newcommand{\foreachmultidots}[2][0mm]{
    \vspace{#1}
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#2}{
        \par\noindent\dotfill\par\vspace{#1}
    }
}
\newcommand{\foreachmultirules}[2][0mm]{
    \vspace{#1}
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#2}{
        \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\[#1]
    }
}

\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{count}
\newcommand{\forloopmultidots}[2][0mm]{
    \vspace{#1}
    \forloop{count}{1}{\value{count} <#2}{
        \par\noindent\dotfill\par\vspace{#1}
    }
}
\newcommand{\forloopmultirules}[2][0mm]{
    \vspace{#1}
    \forloop{count}{0}{\value{count} <#2}{
        \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\[#1]
    }
}
\begin{document}
\noindent\verb|\usepackage{pgffor}|
\foreachmultidots{8} % no Value -> default value [0mm]
\foreachmultirules[3mm]{8} % positive Value to increse height

\noindent\verb|\usepackage{forloop}|
\forloopmultidots[-1mm]{8} % negative Value to decrese height
\forloopmultirules[2mm]{8} % positive Value to increse height
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use `\linespread{1.25}\selectfont` to set the linespread relativly to the standard globally.

Comment: May I suggest an alternative solution, namely, using a strut (that is, a zero-width, and hence invisible vertical rule) at the beginning of each line?